# Clear all Icons/Markers/InfoWindows in Subgurim Maps

Tags: google-maps, subgurim-maps

I've placed, say 20 InfoWindows+Markers+Icons on my map.

When the user pans to the right, I want to remove all existing InfoWindows+Markers+Icons on my map and paint the new ones.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it, it's
subgurim_GMap1.clearOverlays();

in javascript, 
where subgurim_GMap1 is the GMap_Id of your map

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do the clearing and painting yourself, the easiest option would be to use [MarkerManager](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/), from the [Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can add custom javascript to the Subgurim GoogleMaps control using "[CustomJavascript](http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/ejemplos/ejemplo_99000_Custom-Javascript.aspx)" or "[CustomInsideJavascript](http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/ejemplos/ejemplo_99001_Custom-Inside-Javascript.aspx)"

On the other hand, as Chris B says, it will be very useful to use the Subgurim [MarkerManager](http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/ejemplos/ejemplo_96250_MarkerManager.aspx).